# Drush archive-dump override sql dump name

Tags: drush

Is there a way to use `drush archive-dump` but to pass it somehow the name of sql file it dumps into archive? Current name is too long (full path with dots instead / and # to separate path and site name) and not as useful so I would love to override its name (like I can do with tar.gz name with `--destination` parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to stipulate what the sql dump file should be named.  See the [archive-dump source code](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.0.3/commands/core/archive.drush.inc#L217) for reference.

Wouldn't be too hard to adjust; PRs would be welcome.